# Apps you can Add Option Missing in Custom Master Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have created a Custom Master Page for my SharePoint Site. Everything looks fine but I am trying to create a list from Template uploaded in Gallery.

I can't see "Apps you can Add" Option if I use this newly created:

[image]

I want the following Option to be visible in this Site:

[image]

Can someone help me in this?

Comment: I think you are checking it on two different tenants/sites. Can you try checking on same site? Are those both same type of sites (team or communication)?

Comment: I have also checked on the same site, when I add seattle as the Master Page, this Option is available but when I put my Master Page, it's not visible